# How to know whether a custom profile is being used or not?

Tags: profile

I need to remove a profile which is not being used anywhere in my sandbox. But i am not sure whether it is being used or not. How can i come to know that ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Do you mean it isn't used in your sandbox, but you want to be sure it is not being used in production?

Comment: yup!! exactly!!

Comment: How did you go about verifying in your sandbox? Can't you reproduce those steps in production?

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to create a project with one of the IDEs (Force.com plugin for Eclipse, MavensMate, BrainEngine etc.), check out everything (all metadata) and perform a search through each folder/file either through the IDE or another app on your OS for the profile name and check the results.

Don't forget to also search for the profile ID as well as the Name.

Also make sure you don't have any users assigned to it, they'll all need to be switched to another profile before you can delete it.

Comment: What would he be searching for in the project. It's early (and only one cup of coffeed so far), but "in use" is simply, "are there any users assigned". No users using the profile...I can delete it, can't I?

Comment: @Peter, he'd be searching for any references to the profile Name or ID, e.g. apex code that executes critical business logic and has referenced the profile ID. I don't think you can just delete the profile if you have one or multiple users assigned to it.

Comment: Ok, yeah. I could see if there is any Apex code/VF pages relying on that profile. That's a good point. Especially since this would outright break those tests, and the references would not be checked. Perhaps formulas? But the only thing I can think that would block the delete is a user referencing that profile (deactivated users, too, perhaps?).